# Snippet Clarification byte array to port number

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I have a byte array that contains 6 bytes last 2 represents the port number while searching for a way two convert these last to bytes to a port number i have come across this snippet,

```
            int port = 0;
        port |= peerList[i+4] & 0xFF;
        port <<= 8;
        port |= peerList[i+5] & 0xFF;
```

it works but i need some clarification as to how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   =======================
>   |  byte 5  |  byte 6  |
>   |----------|----------|
>   | 01010101 | 01010101 |
>   =======================
> ```

Basically, it takes byte #5, shift is 8 bits to the left resulting in `0101010100000000` and then uses the bitwise or operator to put the byte 6 in the place of zeros.

Comment: The & 0xFF is needed to keep the resulting int from being negative if the original byte has it's top bit as 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
    int port = 0;                       // Start with zero
    port |= peerList[i+4] & 0xFF;       // Assign first byte to port using bitwise or.
    port <<= 8;                         // Shift the bits left by 8 (so the byte from before is on the correct position)
    port |= peerList[i+5] & 0xFF;       // Assign the second, LSB, byte to port.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code simply takes the last 2 bytes from the array and uses them as a big-endian number.

Usually in network packets the port number is transferred in big-endian (meaning the byte with the lower address is more significant).

The code takes byte number i+4 and uses it as the MSB and byte i+5 as the LSB of the port number.